# Why using map in render slow/freeze app if there is a lot of entries?

Tags: android, performance, react-native, dictionary, render

I have a screen (n°1) with 1 button. When I click on it I have to wait from 1 to 4 seconds to see next screen (n°2) and it's really really slow and boring.

I find the problem come from this line:
{this.state.db.map((item, index) => this.renderItem(item, index))}

db contains 327 entries. When db contains 2 entries, it render fast.

Why? And what can I do ?

Comment: Have you tried to find out how much time your app spends doing DB? rendering?

Comment: db is an imported json file, so it should be fast (but I've not checked). Rendering is slow yes, here is my problem, from 1 to 4 seconds, it depends but it's near to 4 secs in most of my tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) as it is specifically designed for this use case.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try it but I'm not sure it's what I search. I'm not rendering only a text.

Comment: It can render anything.

Comment: Ah ok my bad! I'll try it. Do you know why FlatList should be faster than map? (and why map is so slow)

Comment: It only renders a chuck of list you see in viewport.

Comment: It works! I don't understand why yet but it works. Thanks a lot!